# Redux Updating Array inside Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I'm having problem with updating an array inside an object in my state. Currently my state is an array, containing objects. Each object has another array containing data, like below:

```html
const initialState = [
  {
    id: 0,
    data: ["String1"]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    data: ["String2"]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to update the "data" array inside each of the object. This is how I do it, and I don't see changes to the array in the Redux Devtools

```html
case STORE_DATA:
  return state.map(object => {
    if (object.id !== action.payload.id) { 
      return object;
    } else {
      return {
        ...object,
        data: [
          ...object.data,
          action.payload.data,
        ],
      };
    }
  });
```

Comment: check if type of object.id is the same as `action.payload.id` if not that is the reason

Comment: have you kept the reducer in the `combineReducer` in your `rootReducer`?

Comment: the code looks fine. Check whether the code is being executed properly or not. Check if the reducer is called or not. And also check that the `object.id` matches the `action.payload.id`.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if type of `action.payload.data` is `array` or `string`. If it is `array` type you should populate it.

```js
case STORE_DATA:
  return state.map(object => {
    if (object.id !== action.payload.id) { 
      return object;
    } else {
      return {
        ...object,
        data: [
          ...object.data,
          ...action.payload.data, // here
        ],
      };
    }
  });
```

Comment: type of action.payload.data is string

Comment: I cannot see any incorrect code. can you upload your whole project to codesandbox?

Comment: The project is very complicated and I can't set it up on code sandbox. What I can do is upload the reducer, action, store related to this problem to codesandbox. They won't compile and run though, but at least the code have somewhere to go.
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-gauss-xcxtc?file=/src/index.js
There are 4 main files: reducer, action, index and store

Comment: Here is a sample project based on the main project, used to replicate the same function, and it works. https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-cloud-2lihm